# Get column a and column b through first parameter to last parameter

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-express

I'm newbie on tsql and stuck on this problem. Can anyone help this prb? 
I have a table like below; (use SQL 2008 Express Edt.)

```
ID    COL1    COL2
1      7      2
2      7      3
3      7      4
4      7      5
5      9      2
6      9      3
7      9      4
8      9      5
9      11     2
10     11     3
11     11     4
12     11     5
```

how to use select query to fetch between 7/3 and 11/2 (both columns and first/last rows included)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID BETWEEN 2 AND 10`? You have to give some more details on the problem.

Comment: could you show the required output.

Comment: as you can see that the col1 repeated number and col2 sequantial. Table, temporary and I don't use ID column. When user select parameter on asp page; first COL1 + COL2 and last COL1 + COL2 stored proc can select between this all values.

Comment: thnx for your repy syed mohsin. Here is what i need; 2 7 3
3 7 4
4 7 5
5 9 2
6 9 3
7 9 4
8 9 5
9 11 2

Comment: No prob. Mikael answer is a good one. Did it helped u?

Comment: yes it helped me. thnx syed mohsin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce08c/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  ID int,
  COL1 int,
  COL2 int
)

insert into YourTable values
(1   ,7     ,2),
(2   ,7     ,3),
(3   ,7     ,4),
(4   ,7     ,5),
(5   ,9     ,2),
(6   ,9     ,3),
(7   ,9     ,4),
(8   ,9     ,5),
(9   ,11    ,2),
(10  ,11    ,3),
(11  ,11    ,4),
(12  ,11    ,5)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from YourTable
where (COL1 > 7 and COL1 < 11) or
      (COL1 = 7 and COL2 >= 3) or
      (COL1 = 11 and COL2 <= 2)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce08c/1/0)**:

```
| ID | COL1 | COL2 |
--------------------
|  2 |    7 |    3 |
|  3 |    7 |    4 |
|  4 |    7 |    5 |
|  5 |    9 |    2 |
|  6 |    9 |    3 |
|  7 |    9 |    4 |
|  8 |    9 |    5 |
|  9 |   11 |    2 |
```

Comment: thnx Mikael but your query result set fetching to last table rows too. Not to 11/2 condition.

Comment: @ZEK I have updated the answer with a SQL Fiddle that you can try.

Comment: thnx Mikael your query is correct. Trying temp table is wrong on VS query editor.